# Jest test a promise wrapped request

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, jestjs

I have a `request` call wrapped in a promise chain as follows

```
  import * as request from 'request';

  public async getData (): Promise<string> {
    const token = await this.util.getToken();
    const options = {
      withCredentials: true,
      Connection: 'keep-alive'
    };
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
      request(this._Host, options, (err, data) => {
        if (err != null) {
          return reject('Fetch Failed');
        }
        const values = JSON.parse(data.body);
        this._result = values.result;
        return resolve('Fetch Success');
      });
    });
  }
```

And I'm using `jest` to test this method using the following code

```
it('should fetch data', async(done) => {
  const classobj = new ClassName(config);
  (classobj as any).util.getToken.// tslint:disable-line
   mockResolvedValue('some-token');
  const spy = jest.mock('request', (path, options) => {
    return Promise.resolve('Fetch Success');
  });
  const dispatcher = await classobj.getData().then(done());
});
```

However the code inside `request` block never gets triggered. But the test is displayed as running successfully as well. I also noticed that if I pass a values that's already resolved within the `return new Promise` then the code block is getting triggered without any issues. Is there something that's missing in this code to test the `request` call?

Comment: No need to return a `promise`. `async` function will automatically wrap your return type as `promise` so you just need to use `return` and `throw error` and `async` takes care of the rest.

Comment: @Xaqron I think in this case `request` library doesn't return a `promise` by default and since I use this method in a lambda i'm wrapping it in a `promise`.

Comment: Yes, and same authors have provided wrapper libraries like [this](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native) one.